# Override Magento_Sales::email/items/shipment/default.phtml Template (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, module, sales-order, template-override

I am trying to override `Magento_Sales::email/items/shipment/default.phtml`
Here is my layout file
app/code/Mod/Sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_shipment_renderers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Creditmemo Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.shipment.renderers">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Mod_Sales::email/items/shipment/default.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Added phtml in

```
app/code/Mod/Sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/shipment/default.phtml
```

But file did not override the call still comes into vendor file.
Any thoughts what's missing ?

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Try This**

**sales_email_order_shipment_renderers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Creditmemo Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.shipment.renderers.default">
            <action method="setTemplate" >
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Mod_Sales::email/items/shipment/default.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.shipment.renderers.grouped">
            <action method="setTemplate" >
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Mod_Sales::email/items/shipment/default.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.shipment.renderers.bundle">
            <action method="setTemplate" >
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Mod_Sales::email/items/shipment/default.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.shipment.renderers.downloadable">
            <action method="setTemplate" >
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Mod_Sales::email/items/shipment/default.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Hello, is their any specific reason why override these many referenceBlock ?

Comment: because of there are multiple type of product to show into email that's why we override these many referenceBlock.

Comment: ok thanks let me check the answer.

Comment: ok check and update me.

Comment: you can get product id from this item obj. And load product by that product id.

Comment: Can you please add it as answer, so i can directly check ?

Comment: Please add this line print_r(get_class_methods($_item)); and add to your question

Comment: if above answer is work for you so please accept answer.

Comment: hello, i have checked this & its not working. Module phtml file is not getting called.

Comment: Any thoughts @Msquare

Comment: In our module this works. I think you doing something wrong.

Comment: layout

app/code/Mod/Sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_shipment_renderers.xml

phtml file

app/code/Mod/Sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/shipment/default.phtml

Comment: It seems to be correct

Comment: Please have a look at - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/331319/not-able-to-get-product-image
i have added class methods in question also

Comment: It did not included configurable product type ?