# Not able to get product image

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, product-images, email-templates

How to get product image in "default.phtml" file ?

```
Magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/shipment/default.phtml
```

I am getting the shipped product object in this file but none of the method is working here for product image i.e (`getImageUrl()`).

Is their any way i can get product image in this file ?

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var $_item \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
$_item          = $block->getItem();
?>
<tr>
    <td class="item-info<?=($_item->getItemOptions() ? ' has-extra' : '')?>">
        <p class="product-name"><?=$_item->getName()?></p>
        <p class="sku"><?='SKU'?>: <?=$_item->getSku()?></p>
        <p class="sku"><?='Price'?>: <?=$_item->getPrice()?></p>
        <?php if ($_item->getItemOptions()): ?>
            <dl class="item-options">
                <?php foreach ($_item->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
                    <dt><strong><em><?=$option['label']?></em></strong></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <?=nl2br($option['value'])?>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php $addInfoBlock = $_item->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock();?>
        <?php if ($addInfoBlock): ?>
            <?=$addInfoBlock->setItem($_item->getOrderItem())->toHtml()?>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?=$_item->getDescription()?>
    </td>
    <td class="item-qty"><?=(float) $_item->getQty()?></td>
</tr>
                Array
(
    [0] => __construct
    [1] => setShipment
    [2] => getShipment
    [3] => setOrderItem
    [4] => getOrderItem
    [5] => setQty
    [6] => register
    [7] => getAdditionalData
    [8] => getDescription
    [9] => getName
    [10] => getOrderItemId
    [11] => getParentId
    [12] => getPrice
    [13] => getProductId
    [14] => getQty
    [15] => getRowTotal
    [16] => getSku
    [17] => getWeight
    [18] => setParentId
    [19] => setRowTotal
    [20] => setPrice
    [21] => setWeight
    [22] => setProductId
    [23] => setOrderItemId
    [24] => setAdditionalData
    [25] => setDescription
    [26] => setName
    [27] => setSku
    [28] => getExtensionAttributes
    [29] => setExtensionAttributes
    [30] => getEventObject
    [31] => getCustomAttributes
    [32] => getCustomAttribute
    [33] => setCustomAttributes
    [34] => setCustomAttribute
    [35] => setData
    [36] => unsetData
    [37] => getData
    [38] => setId
    [39] => __sleep
    [40] => __wakeup
    [41] => setIdFieldName
    [42] => getIdFieldName
    [43] => getId
    [44] => isDeleted
    [45] => hasDataChanges
    [46] => setDataChanges
    [47] => getOrigData
    [48] => setOrigData
    [49] => dataHasChangedFor
    [50] => getResourceName
    [51] => getResourceCollection
    [52] => getCollection
    [53] => load
    [54] => beforeLoad
    [55] => afterLoad
    [56] => isSaveAllowed
    [57] => setHasDataChanges
    [58] => save
    [59] => afterCommitCallback
    [60] => isObjectNew
    [61] => beforeSave
    [62] => validateBeforeSave
    [63] => getCacheTags
    [64] => cleanModelCache
    [65] => afterSave
    [66] => delete
    [67] => beforeDelete
    [68] => afterDelete
    [69] => afterDeleteCommit
    [70] => getResource
    [71] => getEntityId
    [72] => setEntityId
    [73] => clearInstance
    [74] => getStoredData
    [75] => getEventPrefix
    [76] => addData
    [77] => getDataByPath
    [78] => getDataByKey
    [79] => setDataUsingMethod
    [80] => getDataUsingMethod
    [81] => hasData
    [82] => toArray
    [83] => convertToArray
    [84] => toXml
    [85] => convertToXml
    [86] => toJson
    [87] => convertToJson
    [88] => toString
    [89] => __call
    [90] => isEmpty
    [91] => serialize
    [92] => debug
    [93] => offsetSet
    [94] => offsetExists
    [95] => offsetUnset
```

Comment: $_item          = $block->getColor(); is also not working

Answer (score 0):

You can see On this link

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/How-to-include-Product-Image-in-Email/td-p/454626

Or

[Magento 2 product image in new order email](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147762/magento-2-product-image-in-new-order-email)

Answer (score 0):

please add below code at path like:
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/shipment/default.phtml

```
<?php $_imageHelper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');?>
<?php $product = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());?>


//image
<img src="<?= $_imageHelper->init($product, 'small_image', ['type'=>'small_image'])->keepAspectRatio(true)->resize('65','65')->getUrl();?>" alt="<?= __('Product Image');?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try This

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());

$helperImport = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

$imageUrl = $helperImport->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')
                ->setImageFile($product->getSmallImage()) // image,small_image,thumbnail
                ->resize(380)
                ->getUrl();
echo $imageUrl;
```